# How to download a table of internet that if the copies in excel it is entered all in a single box?

Tags: r, excel, web-scraping

When I try to import tables from certain web pages. The Excel function to import tables from the web, you can not. These tables when copied and paste, are usually pasted into a single Excel cell.

I would like to know if there is any solution for this, either from Excel or from **R**.

Comment: I introduce a link as an example table I want to import:

http://sports.williamhill.es/bet_esp/es/betting/t/295/Inglaterra+-+Premier+League.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use a website to convert the `html table` to `.csv` then import the `.csv` in excel.
Just [search](https://www.google.com/search?q=html%20table%20to%20csv&oq=html%20table%20to%20csv&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60.6182j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) on google for `html table to csv`. Here is an example: [Html to csv](http://www.convertcsv.com/html-table-to-csv.htm).

Answer (score 0):

With Excel you can import data from Web pages if you click on Data > From Web.

Then you copy/paste the url where your table is and you choose which table you want to import.

See this video for more details : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FZSR8DA01jQ

This assumes your Excel version is 2010 or more recent.

Comment: My problem is for tables that do not detect this excel function. 
For example: http://sports.williamhill.es/bet_esp/es/betting/t/295/Inglaterra+-+Premier+League.html